# Problema al actualizar datos de objetos usando EditText en un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Espero que me entiendan.
Tengo una activity que contiene un RecyclerView. En este llamo datos de una API de algunos productos el cual son listados y el stock de cada artículos queda en un EditText. Necesito verificar si uno o todos los datos son modificados y rescatar en un ArrayList (tal vez) de los objetos ya actualizados al presionar un botón para efectuar la modificación en mi base de datos. Dejo el código a continuación.

activity_minuta_entrega2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ActivityMinutaEntrega">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_confirmar_entrega"
            android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Datos de entrega"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_minuta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_confirmar_entrega"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:text="Confirmar Edición" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_minuta_entrega.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvItemListRuta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_pitch"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="12">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/status_bar_ruta"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_total"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_textos"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_name_article"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Articulo" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_description_article"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="descripcion " />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sustrac"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_cantidad"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityMinutaEntrega.java

```
public class ActivityMinutaEntrega extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.txt_nombre_ruta)
    TextView txt_ruta;
    private RutasSingleton rutasSingleton;
    RecyclerView recycle_lista_minuta_entrega;
    private MinutaEntregaAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RutaDetalleSingleton rutaDetalleSingleton;
    private Button btn_confirmar_entrega;

    private ArrayList<BultosDetalle> bultosDetalleArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rutasSingleton = RutasSingleton.getInstance();
        rutaDetalleSingleton = RutaDetalleSingleton.getInstance();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_minuta_entrega2);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        txt_ruta.setText("Ruta:" + rutasSingleton.getRutaId());

        btn_confirmar_entrega = findViewById(R.id.btn_confirmar_entrega);

        recycle_lista_minuta_entrega = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_minuta);
        traerDetalleBultos(String.valueOf(rutaDetalleSingleton.getRutaDetId()));


        btn_confirmar_entrega.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

    }

    public void traerDetalleBultos(String rutasdetid) {

        DetalleBultoServiceApi detalleBultoServiceApi = new DetalleBultoServiceApi();
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityMinutaEntrega.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false); // set cancelable to false
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait"); // set message
        progressDialog.show();

        mAdapter = new MinutaEntregaAdapter(detalleBultoServiceApi.traerBultosDetalle(ActivityMinutaEntrega.this, rutasdetid, new DetalleBultoResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void requestStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void requestCompleted() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                recycle_lista_minuta_entrega.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recycle_lista_minuta_entrega.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recycle_lista_minuta_entrega.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void requestEndedWithError(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("error", "" + error);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

DetalleBultoServiceApi.java

```
public class DetalleBultoServiceApi {

    DetalleBultoResponseListener mListener;
    ArrayList<BultosDetalle> bultos;
    BultosDetalle bulto;

    public ArrayList<BultosDetalle> traerBultosDetalle(Context context, String rutasDetId, DetalleBultoResponseListener mlistener) {
        this.mListener = mlistener;
        bultos = new ArrayList<>();
        mListener.requestStarted();
        DatosUsuario datosUsuario = DatosUsuario.getInstance();

        try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put(TAG_USUARIO,datosUsuario.getUsername());
            jsonBody.put(TAG_CLAVE, datosUsuario.getPass());
            jsonBody.put(TAG_SIM,datosUsuario.getSim());
            jsonBody.put(TAG_RUTAS_DETALLE_ID, rutasDetId);


                MyJsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new MyJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.BASE_URL + Config.API_DETALLE_BULTO, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response.toString());

                    JSONObject jsbulto = null;
                    try {

                        if (response != null) {
                            BultoSingleton bultoSingleton = BultoSingleton.getInstance();
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                jsbulto = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                bulto = new BultosDetalle();

                                bulto.setRutasDetId(jsbulto.getInt(TAG_RUTAS_DETALLE_ID));
                                bulto.setBultos(jsbulto.getInt(TAG_BULTO));
                                bulto.setCodigoArticulo(jsbulto.getString(TAG_CODIGO_ARTICULO));
                                bulto.setDescripcion(jsbulto.getString(TAG_DESCRIPCION));
                                bulto.setUnidadMedida(jsbulto.getString(TAG_UNIDAD_MEDIDA));
                                bulto.setNumeroSerie(jsbulto.getString(TAG_NUMERO_SERIE));
                                bulto.setFechaVecto(jsbulto.getString(TAG_FECHA_VENCICMIENTO));
                                bulto.setArmado(jsbulto.getInt(TAG_ARMADO));
                                bulto.setRevisionDetId(jsbulto.getInt(TAG_REVISION_DET_ID));
                                bulto.setEanTrece(jsbulto.getString(TAG_EAN_TRECE));

                                if (bultoSingleton.getNroBulto() == bulto.getBultos()){
                                    bultos.add(bulto);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        mListener.requestCompleted();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("LOG_RESPONSE", error.toString());
                    mListener.requestEndedWithError(error);
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return params;
                }


            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return bultos;
    }
}
```

MinutaEntregaAdapter.java

```
public class MinutaEntregaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MinutaEntregaAdapter.MinutaEntregaViewHolder>{

    private List<BultosDetalle> mDataset;
    private static ClickListener clickListener;
    private BultoSingleton bultoSingleton;
    private int cant;
    private String[] array;

    public List<BultosDetalle> getmDataset() {
        return mDataset;

    }



    public static class MinutaEntregaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        public TextView txt_articulo, txt_descripcion;
        public EditText cantidad;
        public Button btn_add, btn_disc;
        public CheckBox status;

        public MinutaEntregaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txt_articulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_article);
            txt_descripcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_description_article);
            cantidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_cantidad);
            btn_add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            btn_disc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sustrac);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_total);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        MinutaEntregaAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);

        void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
    }


    public MinutaEntregaAdapter(List<BultosDetalle> mDataset) {
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MinutaEntregaAdapter.MinutaEntregaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_minuta_entrega, parent, false);
        MinutaEntregaAdapter.MinutaEntregaViewHolder viewHolder = new MinutaEntregaAdapter.MinutaEntregaViewHolder(listItem);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MinutaEntregaViewHolder holder, int position) {


        bultoSingleton = BultoSingleton.getInstance();

        holder.txt_articulo.setText(mDataset.get(position).getCodigoArticulo());
        holder.txt_descripcion.setText(mDataset.get(position).getDescripcion());

        holder.cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).getArmado()));

        holder.status.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.status.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (holder.status.isChecked()) {
                    holder.cantidad.setText("0");
                    cant = 0;
                } else {
                    holder.cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).getArmado()));
                    cant = mDataset.get(position).getArmado();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.cantidad.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                    cant = 0;
                } else {
                    cant = Integer.parseInt(holder.cantidad.getText().toString());
                }
                cant++;
                holder.cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cant));
            }
        });

        holder.btn_disc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.cantidad.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                    cant = 0;
                } else {
                    cant = Integer.parseInt(holder.cantidad.getText().toString());
                }

                if (cant == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "La cantidad de arículos no puede ser menor a 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    cant--;
                }
                holder.cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cant));
            }
        });

        holder.cantidad.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (holder.cantidad.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    holder.cantidad.setText("0");
                    cant = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

[image]

El valor que aparece en los EditText son los que rescato de la BD.
Cualquier información extra intentaré responder a la brevedad.

Answer (score 1):

Si actualizas los datos que obtienes al consultar una API y quieres que estos cambios se reflejen en tu `RecyclerView`, simplemente debes notificar este cambio al `Adapter` mediante el método [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()):

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

> [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) Notifica a los observadores adjuntos que
>   los datos subyacentes han cambiado y que cualquier Vista que refleje
>   el conjunto de datos debería actualizarse.

Comment: No, lo que necesito son los datos para enviar una respuesta a mi servidor y que este efectúe los cambios en la BD, me da igual de que manera rescatarlos, pero no entiendo como trabajar los datos del adapter y juntarlos con mi botón en el activity. Hasta el momento solo había tenido que enviar un único objeto y creaba una instancia única por donde sacaba los datos.

Comment: Ok, cual es el método que usas para enviar los datos, tienes un método?

Comment: Una vez teniendo los datos, solo creo un json y lo envío a través de la API, mi problema va más atrás. Yo recibo una lista de objetos, este pasa a mi adapter y se lista en el recyclerview en donde un parámetro numérico se queda en un EditText. De estos si o si se debe modificar uno o más, esa es la data que necesito. No tengo ningún método porque no supe siquiera como hacerlo.

Comment: entonces quieres actualizar (POST) todos los datos que estan en los EditText?

Comment: Exacto, no se cual sea la mejor manera para trabajar esos EditText y enviar los datos presionando el botón que está en el Activity ya que el manejo de la información la he estado haciendo en el Adapter